# How to round a number down to 8 decimal places if its over 8 decimal places in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bitcoin

I'm trying to check if a number inputed has over 8 decimal places and if it does then I want to round it back down to 8 decimal places. However, when I input the number 1.234001, it automatically rounds it to 8 decimal places. (1.234001 / 0.00000001) % 1 = 0 so I'm not sure why its rounding it. 
Here's my code

```
var SAT = 0.00000001;
if(!isNaN(input.value) && ((input.value / SAT) % 1 != 0)) {
                input.value = parseFloat(input.value).toFixed(8);
                console.log(6);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it in this way:

```
function nrOfDecimals(number) {
    var match = (''+number).match(/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/);
    if (!match) { return 0; }

    var decimals =  Math.max(0,
       (match[1] ? match[1].length : 0)
       // Correct the notation.
       - (match[2] ? +match[2] : 0));

     if(decimals > 8){
        //if decimal are more then 8
        number = parseFloat(number).toFixed(8);
     }
     //else no adjustment is needed
     return number;
}
```

Comment: Works great, something weird I noticed though is that it won't let me command/control A and select all of the input.

Comment: I can not follow you anymore. You wanted to check if a number has more than 8 decimals and this function does just that. I don't know in which way and where you are using it. Maybe you can post your HTML so I can see what are you trying to select and (maybe) I can also help you with this.

Comment: No its fine don't worry about it.